# context path is not getting in URL

Tags: grails, spring-security

Iam using spring-security-core 3.1.1 in my grails 3.2.7 application. I have added the following code in my application.yml

```html
server:
   contextPath: /LGP
   port: 9090
```

So the appcode LGP will be appended to my URL. eg: http://localhost:9090/LGP/home

But the problem is when i'm using the `<a href="/projects">Projects</a>` tag, the URL is becoming http://localhost:9090/home , the app code (LGP) getting skipped from the URL.
Why this is happening?
For the time being i update the tag as `<a href="/${request.contextPath}/projects">Projects</a>` but this gives the URL only as

> lgp/projects

the http://localhost:9090/ section is getting missed.

Why this is like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're linking to a controller use:

```
<g:link controller="projects">Projects</g:link>
```

If you're linking to e.g. a static resource use:

```
<g:link uri="/projects">Projects</g:link>
```